# How to force aws-cli or terraform to delete OpsWorks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws

I tried to destroy my infrastructure created using Terraform but when I run `terraform destroy` it destroys everything but failed to destroy OpsWorks. I got the below error while all instance in the OpsWork were already terminated.

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeleteStack
operation: Cannot be deleted - please delete the instances first
```

I tried with `aws-cli` too but same error.

```
aws opsworks delete-stack --region us-west-2 --stack-id my_stack_id --profile myprofile
```

So How I can automate this with Terraform to delete the stack or as there any other way to just remove all the instance from the stack and terminate the OpsWork stack instead of removing one by one instance?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try this manually through the console?  If so, what were the results?

Comment: Yes same error from aws-cli too as i mentioned